# how to return a value from express middleware as a separate module

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

I have put the server setting script into a separate js file called `server.js`. My problem is that I don't know how to get the value of `cookie_key` from the express middleware function and pass it back to the index.js file.

`server.js`:

```
var express = require('express'), 
app = express(), 
http = require('http').createServer(app),
cookie = cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
url = require('url');

module.exports = {

 use_app : function(){
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var cacheTime = 86400000*7; // 7 days
  if (!res.getHeader('Cache-Control')) 
   res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=' + (cacheTime / 1000));
   next();
  }); 
 },

 get_app : function(callback){
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.get('/id/:tagId', function(req, res){ // parse the url parameter to get the file name
   function getkey(err,data){ // get users' session cookie
    var cookie_key;
    if(err)
    {
      callback(err);
    }
    cookie_key = req.cookies["session"];
    callback(cookie_key);
   }
   var filename = req.param("tagId");
   res.sendFile(filename+'.html');
  });
 }

}
```

`index.js`:

```
var server = require('./server'),
server.use_app();
server.get_app(); // how to get the cookie_key when calling this function?
console.log(show_cookie_key_from the module); 
if(cookie_key !== undefined)
{
   // do something
}
```

I tried to write a callback function to fetch the cookie key but I don't think it's working.

Comment: Why do you need to pass it back to index.js? What are you hoping to do with it? I feel like you're splitting your app up in a very poor way.

Answer (score 1):

Update from A.B's answer:

```
var server = require('./server');
server.use_app();
server.get_app(function(cookie){
  if(cookie !== undefined)
  {
    // do something
  }
});
```

But I still think there is something strange about this setup, what exactly are you trying to accomplish with splitting the app up like this?

Comment: I was just thinking about splitting the basic settings (http,express,url,database config) into a separate file so I can reuse them in different projects. It seems like things are getting complicated.

Comment: @timothy you could have edited my answer it gives option to update :)

Comment: How do you plan on using the cookie in this instance? That callback will be called for every request to `/id/:tagId`. I'm trying to figure out the real problem rather than just provide you with something to fix the immediate issue which might set you down a path of more trouble in the future.

Comment: I have been learning how to make a chatroom running on socket.io. The cookie is a php session key. I'm using redis to share data between the chatroom and my php site. The session key will be fetched so that people can be automatically logged in.

Comment: Are you actually running separate node.js and php websites, or is node.js just used for websocket communication?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using callback function and that is being poplulated with cookie value , you can get this like following:

```
var server = require('./server');
server.use_app();
 server.get_app(function(cookie){
cookie_key= cookie
if(cookie_key !== undefined)
{
   // do something
}
});
```

Comment: This does not do what you think it does. You're checking the value of the cookie before the callback is ever called. You have to check the value of the cookie inside the callback.

Comment: @TimothyStrimple, yes, I'm getting `undefined` error with the suggestion.

Comment: @TimothyStrimple edited see. i gave him idea whats happening mistakengly i did